# How I do find unused services and routes on OpenShift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I would like to do a little spring cleaning on our OpenShift Origin instance and clean-up long-gone environments. However, I have many stale services and routes too, i.e. services without matching pods and routes showing to such or non-exisiting services. I would like to delete them in a script, however, I haven't found a sane way to do this with the OpenShift CLI client.

How do I do that?